# Synchronized keyword in not giving expected result in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Not getting expected output by using the synchronized keyword in java

I tried to implement thread synchronization using synchronized keyword in java but am not getting the expected output. The final value of variable cnt should be 20,000 but it's not the case.

```java
package MultiThreading;


class Runner extends Thread {
    
    private static int cnt=0;
    
    public synchronized void func() {
        cnt++;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            func();
        }
    }   
    
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(cnt);
    }
}


public class Synchronization {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        Runner r1 = new Runner();
        Runner r2 = new Runner();
        
        r1.start();
        r2.start();
        
        try {
            r1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
            
        try {
            r2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        r1.print();
                
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: public **static** synchronized void func - you are modifying class field

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov That's right. Post it in answer. I will upvote.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov and also please explain how static is doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the needed *happens-before* relationship when modifying shared state, you have to synchronize on the same object each time<sup>**1**</sup>. Your `cnt` field is static, which means it's shared between all instances of `Runner`. Yet your `func()` method is an instance method. Making an instance method `synchronized` is the same as doing:

```java
public void func() {
  synchronized (this) {
    // method body...
  }
}
```

Where `this` refers to the instance of the class the method was invoked on. Since you create two instances of `Runner`, your threads are synchronizing on two different objects while reading and writing `cnt`. Thus, you get "unexpected" output due to race conditions and other concurrency issues.

In your case, one solution is to make `func()` static. Making a static method `synchronized` is the same as doing:

```java
public static void func() {
  synchronized (EnclosingClass.class) {
    // method body...
  }
}
```

Where `EnclosingClass` is the class where the method is declared (e.g., `Runner`, in your case). The class literal returns an instance of `java.lang.Class` representing the class, which is a singleton<sup>**2**</sup>, meaning you end up synchronizing on the same object.

---

<sup>**1.** This is "per state". In other words, different state can be guarded by different objects, so long as the threads synchronize on the correct object when interacting with particular state. For instance, making `cnt` non-static instead of making `func()` static would also make your code correct, at least from a concurrency perspective (you'd have to change some things to demonstrate multiple threads accessing the same state).</sup>

<sup>**2.** There is actually one instance of `java.lang.Class` per class. So, two calls to `Foo.class` will give the same instance, but `Foo.class` and `Bar.class` will give two different instances. And even that is simplifying things (the `ClassLoader` that loaded the class is part of its identity, but that's beyond the scope of this answer).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Slaw is correct and goes into the arcane details making java multithreading challenging.

The fundamental problem with synchronization as defined by java is the fact that the shared object should be implemented as a class which controls access to its data members rather than forcing the synchronization calls on the threads accessing the shared data. It should be simple to share data across different thread classes without needing to deal with the arcane details of synchronization in each thread class.

The Ada programming language has accomplished these goals.

An Ada solution to the extremely simple problem the author of this question is attempting to solve demonstrates these principles very well.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   protected counter is
      procedure incr;
      function report return Natural;
   private
      count : Natural := 0;
   end counter;

   protected body counter is
      procedure incr is
      begin
         count := count + 1;
      end incr;

      function report return Natural is
      begin
         return count;
      end report;
   end counter;

   task type countem;

   task body countem is
   begin
      for I in 1 .. 10_000 loop
         counter.incr;
      end loop;
   end countem;

begin
   declare
      runners : array (1 .. 14) of countem;
   begin
      null;
   end;
   Put_Line (Natural'Image (counter.report));
end Main;
```

Ada allows the definition of what it calls protected objects. A protected object is protected against race conditions and unsynchronized access.

Protected objects can have three kinds of methods. Protected procedures implicitly control an unconditional exclusive read-write lock on the protected object. Protected entries implicitly control a conditional exclusive read-write lock on the protected object. Protected functions implicitly control an unconditional shared read lock on the protected object. Protected functions are prohibited from modifying the protected object, hence the read-only lock.

The example above declares a protected object using one protected procedure with no parameters and one protected function with no parameters. The single data member of this protected object is declared in the private part of the protected object specification. The implementations of the protected procedure and the protected function are found in the protected body. Unlike java, Ada separates interface definitions of an object or type from implementation.

The protected body is very simple. All synchronization is implicit and therefore is not seen in the source code. The incr procedure simply increments the count data member declared in the private part of the protected object specification. The function report simply reads and returns the value of count.

Ada tasks are equivalent to java threads. Tasks can be defined as individual task objects or as task types. This example defines a task type with no API beyond the name of the task. The body of the task type definition simply calls counter.incr 10_000 times.

Ada does not have a "join" reserved word. Instead a nested block is declared. In that nested block an array of countem tasks is declared. This example declares an array containing 14 instances of the countem task type. All 14 tasks start as soon as execution passes to the "begin" reserved word in the nested block. The rest of the nested block does nothing, thus its only command is "null;", which indicates that the block intentionally does nothing other than start the 14 tasks. The nested block does not complete until all 14 of the tasks complete, thereby achieving the same behavior as if a programmer joined 14 threads in java.

Following the end of the nested block, and therefore the completion of the 14 tasks, the value of the count is displayed by calling counter.report.

The output of this program is:

```
D:\Ada\Stack_Overflow\simple_synchronization\obj\main.exe
 140000
[2023-03-04 20:25:09] process terminated successfully, elapsed time: 00.85s
```

All synchronization is implicitly performed by the protected object. The tasks simply call the protected procedure incr without calling any synchronization primitives directly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was a big help.